# Python 3 - raise statement

Tags: python, raise

I am currently working through Learning Python by Mark Lutz and David Ascher and I have come across a section of code that keeps bringing up errors. I am aware that that book was written with Python 2 in mind unlike the Pyhton 3 I am using. I was wondering if anyone knew a solution to my problem as I have looked everywhere but I have been unable to find a solution .

.........................

```
MyBad = 'oops'

def stuff( ):
    raise MyBad

try:
    stuff( )
except MyBad:
    print('got it')
```

Comment: What error do you get here? On python 3 I get: `TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed`

Comment: I knew Python 2 allowed any object to be raised as an exception, but never knew [the extent to which `raise` supported it](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise).

Answer (score 14):

Basically, `MyBad` is not an exception, and the `raise` statement can only be used with exceptions.

To make `MyBad` an exception, you must make it extend a subclass of `Exception`. For instance, the following will work:

```
class MyBad(Exception):
    pass

def stuff( ):
    raise MyBad

try:
    stuff( )
except MyBad:
    print('got it')
```

Output:

```
got it
```

However, it's better to raise an instance of an exception class, rather than the class itself, because it allows the use of parameters, usually describing the error. The following example illustrates this:

```
class MyBad(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super().__init__()
        self.message = message

def stuff(message):
    raise MyBad(message)

try:
    stuff("Your bad")
except MyBad as error:
    print('got it (message: {})'.format(error.message))
```

Output:

```
got it (Your bad)
```

Comment: Ah I see. I was really missing the forest for the trees there

Comment: @user8048576 Well, there are many languages that allow to throw non-exception things, so it's a comprehensible mistake ^^

Answer (score 2):

You cannot raise a custom exception without creating a class (at least an empty one).

You can add custom text as you want by using also an __init__ function instead of pass:

```
class MyBad(Exception):
    pass
    # def __init__(self, txt):
    #     print(txt)

def stuff( ):
     raise MyBad('test')

try:
    stuff( )
except MyBad:
    print('got it')
```

If you use pass, you will have :

> got it

If you use the __init__() in comment, you will have

> test and got it